# How to replace special characters as "{" in xquery?

Tags: xquery

I'm trying to remove '}{' by '},{' in xquery:

```
fn:replace($text,'\\}\\{','\\},\\{')
```

and getting an error:

```
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.ParseException: Unexpected meta character
```

Comment: tried : fn:replace($string1,'[\\}\\{]','},{')

Comment: getting from string : string_1 }{  => string_1 },{},{ expected => string_1 },{

Comment: It should be one backslash rather than two. But don't forget that XQuery 3.0 has the "q" flag which means all characters represent themselves, no escaping needed.

Comment: thanks for help , using xquery 1.0 , i'll describe the target : i building json , getting string like :{"x":"y"}{"x":"z"}{"x":"a"} needed {"x":"y"},{"x":"z"},{"x":"a"}

Comment: the input can include3 whitespaces , \n , \t ......

Answer (score 1):

Seems simple:

```
replace($text, '\}\{', '},{')
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kv

If there can be whitespace between the curly braces you can use

```
replace($text, '\}\s*\{', '},{')
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kv/3

Comment: hi , your example including unwanted result : '}' --->  '},{' , only places with '}{' with /n,/t  , whitespaces between them.... resulting '},{' needed

Comment: No idea where you would get that, in https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kv/1 a single curly closing brace `}` is untouched.